# Error while moving List Items into folders -Exception calling "UpdateOverwriteVersion" with 0 argument(s)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I am writing a PowerShell script to move List items into folders. The code is almost complete except for one problem. Every time it throws same exception for every item "**System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Up
dateOverwriteVersion" with "0" argument(s): Cannot open "Shared Documents/Document.ppt.zip": no such
 file or folder.**" It doesn't throw this error if the folder already exists. My code is fairly simple. I am retrieving the year and month of the item's created by date then I am creating the year and month folder(inside year folder) using below code :

```
$yrfolder = $list.AddItem($list.RootFolder.url,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder,$year)
    $yrfolder["Title"] = $year
    $yrfolder["Modified"] = "12/31/$year 00:00:00 AM"
    $yrfolder["Created"] = "12/31/$year 00:00:00 AM"
    $yrfolder["Editor"] = $yrfolder["Author"]        
    $yrfolder.Update()
```

Similarly I am creating the month folder inside the year folder and then moving the item inside it like this :

```
$moveToPath = $web.Url+"/"+$monthfolder.Url
$moveToPath += "/" + $item.ID
$web.GetFile($item.Url).MoveTo($moveToPath)
$item["Modified"] = $modified #replacing the original value of item metadata 
$item["Editor"] = $editor
$item["Modified By"] = $editor
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion() # throws error here
```

But this same code worked on one of the sites where I moved 5000 items successfully. But now it's not. Need Help to debug this.

Comment: "It doesn't throw this error if the folder already exists." - sounds like you have your answer right there

Comment: Why does it throw  error for item.updateoverwriteversion method?

Comment: Because you're trying to move it to a folder that doesn't exist, you write so yourself

Comment: No the folder gets created. But item is not moved inside the folder the first time.